# Can't apply tidyverse code from subset to the whole data

Tags: r, automation, tidyverse

I was given a code to test the differences in SEX in my df, the subset I gave contains SPECIES with both M, F and U in the SEX column but I want to test only the M vs F difference. Some SPECIES also only have one SEX, so one level

The following code works for the following subset of data containing, on all SPECIES, M, F and some with U

```
subset %>%
  select(-RING, -AGE, -FAT) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -SPECIES, -SEX) %>%
  group_by(SPECIES, variable) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    chi_sq_results = map(data, ~ chisq.test(.x$SEX, .x$value)),
    tidied = map(chi_sq_results, tidy)
  ) %>%
  unnest(tidied, .drop = TRUE)


> dput(subset)
structure(list(RING = c("H8309", "K617", "A264905", "A358705", 
"A432721", "O59461", "O92094", "O92095"), SPECIES = c("ACCIPITER NISUS", 
"ACCIPITER NISUS", "ACROCEPHALUS SCIRPACEUS", "ACROCEPHALUS SCIRPACEUS", 
"ACROCEPHALUS SCIRPACEUS", "AEGITHALOS CAUDATUS", "AEGITHALOS CAUDATUS", 
"AEGITHALOS CAUDATUS"), SEX = c("M", "F", "F", "M", "U", "M", 
"F", "U"), AGE = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L), FAT = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L), WEIGHT = c(141, 2885, 118, 11, 145, 
64, 68, 7), WING = c(199, 232, 645, 66, 63, 57, 56, 58), WINGPRI = c(117L, 
167L, NA, 50L, 48L, 42L, 38L, 44L), BEAK = c(192, 204, NA, 182, 
16, 82, 796, 878), TARSUS = c(52, 622, NA, 22, 219, 138, 1654, 
1785)), .Names = c("RING", "SPECIES", "SEX", "AGE", "FAT", "WEIGHT", 
"WING", "WINGPRI", "BEAK", "TARSUS"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    RING = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SPECIES = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SEX = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), AGE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), FAT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), WEIGHT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), WING = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), WINGPRI = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), BEAK = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), TARSUS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("RING", "SPECIES", "SEX", "AGE", 
"FAT", "WEIGHT", "WING", "WINGPRI", "BEAK", "TARSUS")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

But when I try to apply this same code to another subset without U, it does not work, it also does not work in the full df. I believe it doesn't work on the full df because some SPECIES only have one level in the SEX column, eg. SPECIES x only has F (females)

I get this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels.
```

Subset without U:

```
> dput(subsetU)
structure(list(RING = c("H8309", "K617", "A264905", "A358705", 
"O59461", "O92094"), SPECIES = c("ACCIPITER NISUS", "ACCIPITER NISUS", 
"ACROCEPHALUS SCIRPACEUS", "ACROCEPHALUS SCIRPACEUS", "AEGITHALOS CAUDATUS", 
"AEGITHALOS CAUDATUS"), SEX = c("M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F"), 
    AGE = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L), FAT = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L), WEIGHT = c(141, 2885, 118, 11, 64, 68), WING = c(199, 
    232, 645, 66, 57, 56), WINGPRI = c(117L, 167L, NA, 50L, 42L, 
    38L), BEAK = c(192, 204, NA, 182, 82, 796), TARSUS = c(52, 
    622, NA, 22, 138, 1654)), .Names = c("RING", "SPECIES", "SEX", 
"AGE", "FAT", "WEIGHT", "WING", "WINGPRI", "BEAK", "TARSUS"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hopefully the the data is reproducible, this is the first time I do this

Thank you

Comment: Hello Pedro, i cant rerun your code because i dont have the tidy object. But i think your explanation is right. the chisq.test will fail if one of both inputs has just 1 level.  Just on a sidenote: To me it looks like you would want to search for sex differences in various variables (like weight male vs weight female). If so, i think there would be better tests to do so than the chi square test.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to test differences in 5 variables.
I've had several people tell me the same about the chi square test but it's what my teacher told me to use
Do you have any other recommendation? It would be very usefull

Comment: Ah, so maybe its some part of the exercise to use chisq.test? The problem with chisquare test and non nominal data is, that chi-square won't account for any ordering of the data or the "value" of the data itself. With continous data you might end up with lots of values that are present in just one group and not in the other, which causes problems for the chisquare test. Going to add an example as an answer to show source-code a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

For parametric dependent variables i would use a t-test (or Wilcoxon test if assumptions for t-test are not met) if you are comparing 2 groups. If you want to compare more than 2 groups (like male, female and U-categorie you mentioned) i'd use a one-way-anova (or Kruskal–Wallis if assumptions for anova fail).

```
set.seed(123)

# Dataframe with 2 Variables.
# one is group
# the other one is some sort of continous value choosen randomly from a normal distribution
# for group 1 the values are taken from a ND with mean = 10 and standard deviation = 5
# for group 2 the values are taken from a ND with mean = 30 and standard deviation = 5
# so there should be a clear difference between group 1 and 2
test = data.frame("group" = rep(c(1,2), 50))
test$value = NA
test$value[which(test$group == 1)] = rnorm(50, 10, 5)
test$value[which(test$group == 2)] = rnorm(50, 30, 5)

# A quick look on the data
plot(test$group, test$value)

# t.test to check if there are differences
t.test(formula = value ~ group, data = test)

# > t.test(formula = value ~ group, data = test)
# 
# Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  value by group
# t = -22.452, df = 97.951, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   -22.37724 -18.74280
# sample estimates:
#   mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
# 10.17202        30.73204 

# mean group 1 is around 10 and in group 2 around 30 (as we expected)
# it is very unlikely that this is just a random coincidence. Chances therefore would be only 0.00000000000000022


# lets try this with the chisquare test
chisq.test(test$group, test$value)

# > chisq.test(test$group, test$value)
# 
# Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  test$group and test$value
# X-squared = 100, df = 99, p-value = 0.453
# 
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(test$group, test$value) :
# Chi-Quadrat-Approximation kann inkorrekt sein

# We get a warning (which translates to english as something like Chi-Square-Approximation might be incorrect)
# this is caused because of the many value-cases that are just present in one and not in the other group.
# chisquare needs at least 5 (if i remember right) values per group X value combination to work.
# But still, we get a p-value which indicates, that there is no significant difference (but don't forget the warning)
# Table to show the many value-cases beeing present just in one group
table(test$value, test$group)

# lets split the values by mean and label the ones below the mean as 1 and those above as 2
# and run the chisquare test again.
test$value2 = 1
test$value2[which(test$value > mean(test$value))] = 2
chisq.test(test$group, test$value2)
table(test$value2, test$group)
# now its working and it tells that there is some significant difference in the distribution of 
# value below and above mean between both groups.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definatly run this by my teacher and try to apply a t.test instead